# Working with equilateral pentagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let ABCDE be an equilateral pentagon. If angle A is congruent to angle B then ABCDE is equiangular. I have tried finding congruent triangles but I cannot find any similarities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Let $ABCE$ be a square, $CDE$ be an  equilateral triangle. So, this pentagon is  equilateral, $\angle A=\angle B $ , but not equiangular.